# count no. of strings

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This question was asked in a coding round of a company in our placements.

Given a string consisting of numbers from 1 to 9. We have to arrange the string such that it is divided into groups. We need to count no. of possible strings such that sum of a group<= sum of next consecutive group.

Example1
input : 1234
output: 6
Strings are :

- {1,2,3,4}
- {1,2,34}
- {12,3,4}
- {12,34}
- {1,234}
- {1234}

the first combination here, 1<2<3<4. second combination, 1<2<(3+4). and so on.

Example2
input : 516
output : 3
Strings are :

- {5,16}
- {51,6}
- {516}

Now time taken by brute force way to generate all strings is O(2^(n-1)). 
My question is how to solve it in better than brute force way?

Constraint : input string length 1<=n<=1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can efficiently be solved using [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). I solved it using a two dimensional array called `dp`. To find the number of valid splits where the `end`th character is last and the last string starts from `start`th character, we need to use the previously computed and cached value for the number of valid splits which ends at the `start-1`th character. That number is a sum of all the cached values in `dp[prev_start][start - 1]`, where `prev_start` may be any value between `[0, start)`, such that the sum of elements in `s[prev_start:start-1]` is not greater than the sum of the elements in `s[start:end]`. Here is a solution in `Python3`:

```
def get_count(s):
    N = len(s)
    # Initialize memoization matrix
    # First row all ones, all others zeros
    dp = list()
    dp.append([1] * N)
    for i in range(N - 1):
        dp.append([0] * N)

    # Convert characters to integers
    s = [ord(i) - ord('0') for i in s]

    for start in range(1, N):
        for end in range(start, N):
            for prev_start in range(0, start):
                if sum(s[prev_start:start]) <= sum(s[start:end+1]):
                    dp[start][end] += dp[prev_start][start - 1]

    return sum([dp[i][N - 1] for i in range(N)])

print(get_count('516'))
```

**Note: the time complexity is O(n^4), but you can easily optimize it to O(n^3).**